# SpringUtilities cannot be resolved

Tags: java, api, springlayout

I'm trying one of the Oracle's GUI examples that uses `SpringUtilities`. But the Eclipse gives me and error `Cannot resolve to type` and when I try to compile I get `SpringUtilities cannot be resolved`. I'm using 1.7 JDK, guess I have to add something somewhere but I can't find much info about this problem on the internet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SpringUtilities` isn't included in the JDK/JRE.  It's used in their SpringLayout tutorial,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html

The source is linked to from that page, and can be viewed at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringGridProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java